# Fill in the missing values in a column determined by the column itself and date

Tags: mysql, hive

I have a subscription table looks like the following.
There are about 1 million unique IDs. 
The table lists subscription status when user began subscription service as indicated by 'Sub' and when it unsubscribed as indicated by 'Usub'.

```
ID Year Month Status
A  2014   1    
A  2014   2    
A  2014   3    
A  2014   4    Sub
A  2014   5    
A  2014   6    
A  2014   7    
A  2014   8    Usub 
A  2014   9    
A  2014  10    
A  2014  11    
A  2014  12    
B  2014   1    
B  2014   2    
B  2014   3    
B  2014   4    
B  2014   5    Usub    
B  2014   6    
B  2014   7    
B  2014   8    
B  2014   9    Sub
B  2014  10    
B  2014  11    
B  2014  12    
.    .    .     .
.    .    .     .
.    .    .     .
```

I am looking to fill in the gap between each status updates.
The desired output table would look like the following:

```
ID Year Month Status
A  2014   1    Usub
A  2014   2    Usub
A  2014   3    Usub
A  2014   4    Sub
A  2014   5    Sub
A  2014   6    Sub
A  2014   7    Sub
A  2014   8    Usub
A  2014   9    Usub
A  2014  10    Usub
A  2014  11    Usub
A  2014  12    Usub
B  2014   1    Sub
B  2014   2    Sub
B  2014   3    Sub
B  2014   4    Sub
B  2014   5    Usub
B  2014   6    Usub
B  2014   7    Usub
B  2014   8    Usub
B  2014   9    Sub
B  2014  10    Sub
B  2014  11    Sub
B  2014  12    Sub
.    .    .     .
.    .    .     .
.    .    .     .
```

Although the first table shows both users have more than one status change, any given ID does not necessarily have more than one status change. However, each ID will have at least one status. ie. a user subscribed on 2014/8 and never unsubscribed will have status= Sub on 2014/8.

Comment: Do you want to do it with **MySQL** or with **Hive**?!? Because regular SQL won't do, you need some procedural trick.

Comment: @Samson,I want to do it with Hive, but will also accept mysql approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that with **procedural** code, reading the data in order, and using a variable to store the "state" of the previous record (with a reset on each new ID).
But SQL is *not* procedural.

So **what kind of procedural wrapper** can we get for a standard single-node database (e.g. MySQL) and for a distributed system (e.g. Hive)?

- MySQL has a stored procedure language that supports **cursors** to
  iterate on rows from a SELECT query *(Google will get you a large number of tutorials like [this one](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-cursor/) taken at random)*
- Hive 2.0 also has a kind of [procedural language extension](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=59690156), but it's
  not part of Hive itself -- you must run your procedural script in a
  [specific tool](http://www.hplsql.org/) (and not everyone has Hive 2.0 anyway) -- also, Hive runs distributed queries on a distributed file system, so "shuffling" all the rows on a single client node then iterating with a single-threaded tool sounds very clumsy -- investigate at your own risk
- Hive also has a complicated and cumbersome way to **run arbitrary procedural code in a distributed way** (in each Mapper or each Reducer), with the `TRANSFORM`clause (a Hive traduction of the legacy and poorly-named "Hadoop streaming" feature); unfortunately [the documentation is cryptic](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Transform) *(you'd better get a good old book e.g. "Programming Hive" from O'Reilly)* and when you finally can make it work, well, the performance drop is significant
- or, you may **develop a custom Hive UDF in Java** with a little twist -- i.e. storing the state from previous row in Java variables and using it
  for the current row

Now, **what kind of procedural logic** do you need to implement in your custom query and custom code?

- first, you need the input query to SORT BY key, date
- with a Hive `TRANSFORM` or a Hive UDF, you also need to DISTRIBUTE BY key so that every key has its history processed as a whole, in a single node *(otherwise the results would make absolutely no sense!)*
- define 2 variables for "PreviousRowKey" and "PreviousRowState"
- on 1st row, or on change of Key, then "PreviousRowState = Usub" and "PreviousRowKey = currentKey"
- on change of State then "PreviousRowState = currentState" else force "currentState = PreviousRowState"